# How selecting some variable to put it into search dialog?

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 selecting some variable(php/vue code) with doubleclicking
to put it into search dialog, without copypasting, maybe with some hot keys ?

Thanks!

Comment: What search: in current file or in project/path? In any case, it already works like that: you select some word/variable/function name and hit your shortcut to bring the desired Find functionality -- the selected text will be there. Works like that for me at very least.

Comment: Pls, explain what is " hit your shortcut". I did not see any

Comment: It means: press the shortcut that you use to bring you Search dialog.